# Email in Joomla

Tags: joomla, email, joomla1.5, sendmail

i am having a joomla site, i hosted it in my own lap, using no-ip, the problem is mail function is not working,what may be the problem? how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is configured in the Administration Control Panel, in the "Server" tab, mail settings. Default is to use PHP mail - since PHP is usually configured by the hosting provider to send mail without knowing any additional parameters. So for local installation you need to ensure that either your PHP is configured to send emails, or use the Sendmail or SMTP options in Joomla (and configure them there).

I hope this helps.